# How can save all changed data in details grid (table)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I was worked simple web application using asp.net web api and angularjs (javascript). In this app I have one master grid, and when I click on button inside row, then the modal dialog will be opened. Modal dialog containd detail grid (table) which have many items. See following picture:
[image]

Each items in his data contains parentId. In my case each detail grid item contains id = 1, which we can see in the next picture:
[image]

This solution (when I click 'plus' button) working fine (only Kolicina field can make change). But, we must click row by row plus button for save all changes. My question is, how can implement functionality, in which we will have only one button in modal dialog for save all row changes. I assume that array (with all item changes) should be forwarded to the web api controller method. 
Thanks for any useful information.

**EDIT**
My html modal looks like:

```
<div id="vipZaglavljeModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="overflow:scroll;max-height:700px;width:750px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">VIP Stavke</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="myTableModal" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="padding-left:15px;font-size:medium;">Id</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium">Sifra</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium">Naziv</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium">Kolicina</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium;width:70px;">Prodavnica</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium">***</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="stavka in stavke track by $index">
                        <td style="padding-left:15px;font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;">{{stavka.Id}}</td>
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;">{{stavka.Sifra}}</td>
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;">{{stavka.Naziv}}</td>
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="stavka.Kolicina" style="width:70px;margin-top:-5px;"/></td><!--ng-class="{ nakonStoKliknesSave: kliknutoNaSave[$index] }"-->
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;">{{stavka.Prodavnica}}</td>
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;"><button ng-click="vipZaglavljePut(stavka.Id, stavka)" ng-disabled="((formatDateScope(stavka.VIPZaglavlje.Pocetak) < trenutniDatumIVrijeme && formatDateScope(stavka.VIPZaglavlje.Kraj) < trenutniDatumIVrijeme) || (formatDateScope(stavka.VIPZaglavlje.Pocetak) > trenutniDatumIVrijeme && formatDateScope(stavka.VIPZaglavlje.Kraj) > trenutniDatumIVrijeme) || (formatDateScope(stavka.VIPZaglavlje.Pocetak) > trenutniDatumIVrijeme && formatDateScope(stavka.VIPZaglavlje.Kraj) < trenutniDatumIVrijeme))" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:-5px">+</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="font-size:medium">OK</button>
            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="osnovnaSredstvaDelete()" style="font-size:medium">Da</button>-->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I can. This is angularjs service function:
`var _vipZaglavljePut = function (id, vipZaglavlje) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.put("/api/VIPZaglavlje/" + id, vipZaglavlje).then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result.data);
        },
      function () {
          deferred.reject();
      });
        return deferred.promise;
    }`
**vipZaglavlje** is object.

Comment: This is angularjs controller function:
`$scope.vipZaglavljePut = function (id, vipZaglavlje) {
        VIPZaglavlje.vipZaglavljePut(id, vipZaglavlje).then(
            function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.stavke.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.stavke[i].Id == id) {
                        $scope.stavke[i] = vipZaglavlje;
                    }
                }
            },
            function () { alert("Desila se greška!") });
    }`

Comment: This is web api method [httpput]:
`// PUT: api/VIPZaglavlje/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]VIPStavkePutModel value)
        {
            try
            {
                var userName = User.Identity.Name;
                var VIPStavke = _db.VIPStavke.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
                VIPStavke.Kolicina = value.Kolicina;
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var message = ex.Message;
            }
        }`

Comment: In html I have html table with ng-repeat loop (displayed in picture 1 above). Instead blue 'plus' button, I want implement only one button, at the bottom of the modal (for save all changes).

Answer (score 0):

Do i understand correctly - you want to have only one button for save all `datas` from table. You can add a checkboxes in each row of table and in the top add button which sums all checked datas and send them on 
HTML :

```
   <table id="myTableModal" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="padding-left:15px;font-size:medium;">Id</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium">Sifra</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium">Naziv</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium">Kolicina</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium;width:70px;">Prodavnica</th>
                        <th style="font-size:medium">***</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="stavka in stavke track by $index">
                        <td style="padding-left:15px;font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;">{{stavka.Id}}</td>
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;">{{stavka.Sifra}}</td>
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;">{{stavka.Naziv}}</td>
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="stavka.Kolicina" style="width:70px;margin-top:-5px;"/></td><!--ng-class="{ nakonStoKliknesSave: kliknutoNaSave[$index] }"-->
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;">{{stavka.Prodavnica}}</td>
                        <td style="font-size:medium;padding-top:12px;"> <button class="btn" ng-click="vipZaglavljePut(stavka)">+</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
 <div ng-if="Kolicina">{{id}} : {{Kolicina}}</div>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.vipZaglavljePut = function (stavka){
          console.log(stavka.Kolicina);
          $scope.id = stavka.Id;
          $scope.Kolicina = stavka.Kolicina;
}
```

Here is plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/h1Jao3YfbFCd2n33bQtk?p=preview

Comment: I have edited my post. As you can see, I have input value, for change field 'Kolicina'. Is there a possibility of implementation without a checkbox control?